# Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry, eclipse-product startup fails

Tags: eclipse, startup

I have defined an application porject and created a product definition. I added all my plugins to the product configuration. I although added all required plugins afterwards. I chose "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" as application. The "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application" was added as a required plugin. The "JAVA_HOME" is set properly. I searched for a solution on stackoverflow but no solution meets my conditions. And if I start my generated eclipse product I get:

> !SESSION 2016-06-01 12:39:28.295
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_77 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk,
>   NL=de_DE Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product Command-line arguments:  -os linux
>   -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-01 12:39:29.610 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The
>   applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic,
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger,
>   org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator,
>   org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.WorkflowRunner,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter,
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer.     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

Any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: How do you start your generated product? Through a Run Configuration? If so, did you check this one includes all necessary bundles?

Comment: No, I run it from the systems file browser with the launcher icon.

Comment: The export wizard should put all required plugins into the products export folder - shouldn't it.